# Error:(2) Tag <manifest> attribute package has invalid character '?'

Tags: android

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Bymg.png)

[entI have an error , how can i fix it? My error in instant-run is the following :er image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Bymg.png)

Your advice is important for me!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why did you tagged javasciprt, c#, html? Even the java tag is wrong!

Comment: Please avoid images, but [add code in yur post](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your package name; `é` is not a valid character here. You will have to change your package name to use a simple `e`.